# JQuery - get the min and max date of an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this associative array:

```
[{"start_date":"2018-11-20", "end_date":"2019-01-20", name:"NO Name"},
 {"start_date":"2018-10-10", "end_date":"2019-02-14", name:"Name No"},
 {"start_date":"2019-02-15", "end_date":"2019-03-01", name:"No Name No"}]
```

The value I wanted to get is the `minimun` start date which is `2018-10-10` and the `maximum` end date which is `2019-03-01`. How can I get that?

What Ive Tried:

```
data = '[{"start_date":"2018-11-20", "end_date":"2019-01-20", name:"NO Name"},{"start_date":"2018-10-10", "end_date":"2019-02-14", name:"Name No"},{"start_date":"2019-02-15", "end_date":"2019-03-01", name:"No Name No"}]';

var end_date = new Date();
var start_date = new Date();


for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].end_date > end_date) {
        end_date = data[i].end_date
    }

    if (data[i].start_date > start_date) {
        start_date = data[i].start_date;
    }
}

console.log(end_date);
console.log(start_date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just sort by `start_date` via [**`String.localeCompare`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and then get the fist and last element of the resulting array:

```js
const data = [{ "start_date": "2018-11-20", "end_date": "2019-01-20", name: "NO Name" }, { "start_date": "2018-10-10", "end_date": "2019-02-14", name: "Name No" }, { "start_date": "2019-02-15", "end_date": "2019-03-01", name: "No Name No" } ]

const result = data.sort((a,b) => a.start_date.localeCompare(b.start_date))
console.log(result[0], result[result.length-1])
// Just the dates
console.log(result[0].start_date, result[result.length-1].start_date)
```

Comment: Can I get only the dates?

Comment: Sure: `console.log(result[0].start_date, result[result.length-1].start_date)`